# Table attribute for sorting

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have 3 Tables, a `User table`, a `Tracks table` and a `Likes table`. Users can like as many tracks as they want and one track can be liked by multiple users. In my `Likes table` I have two foreign keys to the User and to the Tracks table.

I'm getting the data from an API, that sends it in the correct order, latest likes sent first. But there's no field like a date when it was liked on. It's only the order. Now I want to put the likes in my database in the correct order, so I made a third column in my `Likes table` that is named `liked_order`. It's an `AUTO_INCREMENTED` value, therefore my foreign keys and the `liked_order` attribute are my primary keys for this table. Unfortunately it is now possible for a user to like a track twice. If the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value wouldn't have to be a primary key everything would be fine.

I've ran out of ideas...

EDIT: I have to use MySQL

Comment: Do you write directly in `Likes` table?

Comment: Yes, when I get the data from the API, my program inserts it into the `Likes` table.

Comment: Can your program assign Order or can you write it in a different table and then copy? So you can avoid using `AUTOINCREMENT`. And what is the problem in current design? `Like order` will never duplicate, so there will be no duplicate keys.

Comment: Yes I can programmaticaly assign the order, but the user can add new likes in the future, so after the first insert my program would have to get the newest order from the database. In my opinion this is work of the database and has nothing to do with my program. I think it's good design to leave that to the database.

There will be no duplicate keys but that's the exact problem, users can like tracks how often they like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the table schema, I see two options:

1. Adjust the schema so that the Foreign Keys(FK) are not part of the Primary Key(PK); only the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column is the PK. The Foreign Keys can still be Unique Indexes to prevent multiple likes of a particular track by the same user. This won't work of course if the FKs are part of a partitioning scheme.
2. Take out the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and add a `TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME` column. The timestamp column [will take up as much space](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) as an `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` column. The downside to this is all rows before adding the timestamp column would not have an order.

Comment: The table schema is nothing fancy, just the two tables with a n:m relation. Which option would be the better approach/Which would you choose?

Comment: Both methods means adjusting PK, so are invasive. However, if you ever see a need to map exactly when likes happen, go with option 2 and take the hit on existing rows not being ordered.

Comment: Well I have no way to know when likes happen, I just get the data from the API, so I'll go with number 1. Thank you very much for your help.